# Add auth headers in Slack's outgoing webhooks?

Tags: slack-api, slack

I am using IBM's OpenWhisk service to stand up a micro-service with a REST endpoint. This expects Basic Auth in it's header when making a POST request to it.

Is it possible to add some custom headers in the Slack Outgoing Webhook settings page so that Slack can hit the OpenWhisk endpoint?

Comment: I don't think that's possible :/

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think that is possible.

If you want to trigger another service based on new messages in a channel I would suggest setting up a Slack App triggered by a message event. That Slack app can then post to your OpenWhisk service according to your needs.

Check out Slack's [Event API](https://api.slack.com/events-api) for details.

This is also the recommend approach, since outgoing webhooks are legacy and should not be used for new projects if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a web action this will expose an API with no authentication required more info here https://console.bluemix.net/docs/openwhisk/openwhisk_webactions.html#openwhisk_webactions

Also there is an example using the Event API for a Slack App here:
https://github.com/ibm-functions/composer/tree/master/docs/tutorials/translateBot#connecting-the-app-to-slack